# Run mono application without terminal window?

Tags: macos, terminal, script, keepass, mono-framework

Is it possible to run a mono application without having the terminal window open? I am trying to run KeePass 2.1.9 using mono on OS X Lion, and it does run fine. The problem is that it has the terminal window open with it, and while it works it is a bit annoying. I have written a script to launch the KeePass application using Automator. It simply does this:

```
Run AppleScript:
on run {input, parameters}
    tell application "Terminal"
    activate
        do script with command "mono /Applications/KeePass/KeePass.exe"
    end tell
end run
```

This works, but it opens up the terminal window along with KeePass. Is it possible to just have it launch KeePass without a terminal window as well? Quitting Terminal doesn't work because that terminals mono with it.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Can't you just *Run Shell Script* and execute `mono /Applications/KeePass/KeePass.exe & ; disown %1`?

Comment: Note: The `with command` parameter is deprecated. Just write `do script "..."`.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this without the terminal window opening. Although the window does open minimized and multiple terminal sessions can stay active. So I set up auto logout after 30 mins.

```
on run {input, parameters}
tell application "Terminal"
    do script with command "mono /Applications/KeePass/KeePass.exe"
end tell
```

Comment: So without the window opening, or with the window minimized?